# Syncing to a Cell Phone Companies NTP Server

Tags: ubuntu, time, ntp, cellular-internet

Not strictly for authentication, I am looking for a way force my Ubuntu NTP Server to use my cell phone companies network time as a basis for all my in home time. I cannot seem to find the address through various search methods.

I can base my clock-in time at work (and when to leave my house) in relation to my cell phones' time (Sprint).  I would like to make that time systemic for my household via NTP.

**Is there a way to find my cellular companies NTP (legally) so I may use it as a source for my Ubuntu based NTP pool?**

Comment: Sorry, I voted to close as this is outside scope for SU.  If your provider is not telling you their NTP server details you should not be using it.  A question would also be why do you need this server - when other servers will prove just as accurate for your apparent use. (Does 0.05 seconds really make a difference to your clock in and leaving time ?)

Comment: http://tf.nist.gov/tf-cgi/servers.cgi .. they're probably using one of those .. and as others have commented, what do the Sprint NTP servers in your area have that one of the many other NTP servers do not? If you need that accurate of synchronization amongst your house-hold devices, you should be using the GPS grid .. My toaster has an EM-506 and an Arduino attached to give microsecond updates that way I don't have to sit and watch it like a 20th century fool!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find that cell phone companies don't, as a standard, use NTP to synchronize phones.  While a provider almost certainly has an NTP server (or dozens) somewhere, that's not what your phone is synching to.

For example, Sprint must use REMARKABLY accurate timing (not timekeeping, which is slightly different) to keep CDMA broadcasts in sync with one another.  If one chip-rate gets out of sync, the quality of all the calls on the tower begin to degrade.  So, the timing (and subsequently, by practice, the timekeeping) is built into CDMA, not into the computer internetworking protcol (NTP).  GSM networks do something similar (since they're TDMA in 2G networks, and a CDMA in 3G+/LTE networks).  The timekeeping system is called [NITZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NITZ) - Network Identity and Time Zone.

Some phones, however, do display time using NTP, which are often hosted by the phone provider (not the service provider).  I believe Google, for example, provides a default NTP server for Android phones.  I believe Apple does the same - but I'm not sure.

So, I don't think there IS an NTP server for the cell company that's intended for the end users - your computer OR your phone.  If you find out otherwise, please post your answer!